# invoke-webrequest to get complete web page with images

Tags: image, powershell, html, gif, powershell-3.0

How do I get the output file to contain the images on the webpage and not just the links to the images?

`PS C:\temp> Invoke-WebRequest http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-51.html -OutFile C:\temp\51.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explore the page a bit to figure out some of details. Here's a complete script which I've tested successfully.

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-51.html |
select -expand images |
select -expand src |
foreach { start-bitstransfer $("http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/{0}" -f $_) C:\Users\Public\Downloads}
```

Comment: This worked pretty well thank you.  It wasn't quite what I wanted as it is a little messier than simply saving the page as a complete web page from the browser.  I ran 'foreach ($x in (1..81)) {Invoke-WebRequest http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-$x.html |
select -expand images |
select -expand src |
foreach { start-bitstransfer $("http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/{0}" -f $_) C:\temp}}'

Comment: && `foreach ($x in (1..81)) {Invoke-WebRequest http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-$x.html -OutFile C:\temp\$x.html}` and it worked. This would be a lot easier if powershell had a webpage complete option.

Comment: `foreach ($x in (1..81)) {Invoke-WebRequest http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/book-Z-H-$x.html |
select -expand images |
select -expand src |
foreach { start-bitstransfer $("http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/sicm/{0}" -f $_) C:\temp}}` formating error