# Powershell: -UseBasicParsing doesn't return all the src elements

Tags: powershell

I was trying to build a simple spider that returns the urls of images from a web-page (not the whole website). And I was using this:

```
  $iwr=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$Uri" -UseBasicParsing
```

But, recently,I found out that sometimes it doesn't return all the image urls, specially the images I was trying to get. And , removing the -UseBasicParsing switch solves the problem as below:

```
$iwr=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$Uri"
```

But, then, it creates another problem. [Edit] As soon as I execute the next statement below:

```
$iwr.Images
```

or

```
$iwr.Images.src
```

it opens up a pop-up saying

```
"You ll need an app to open this about."
```

I have already configured my Internet explorer for first time use way days ago, and i have rechecked it. I changed the user agent to chrome, and i am still getting the pop up.
 How do i prevent this pop-up for any webpage/website in general?

[Edit]: A more efficient script solved the problem, which still uses the -UseBasicParsing switch. It doesn't give any pop-up but returns all the image urls, including the somehow 'masked' urls. The credit goes to @postanote as below:

```
            Clear-Host
            # Regular expression Urls terminating with '.jpg' or '.png' for domain name space
            $regexDomainAddress = "[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)((.jpg(\/)?)|(.png(\/)?)){1}(?!([\w\/]+))"
            $images=((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url -UseBasicParsing).Images `
            | Select-String -pattern $regexDomainAddress -Allmatches `
            | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} `
            | Select-Object $_.Value -Unique).Value -replace 'href=','' `
            | Select-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do sounds very similar to this post:

> How do I get the output file to contain the images on the webpage and
>   not just the links to the images?
>
> [invoke-webrequest to get complete web page with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054030/invoke-webrequest-to-get-complete-web-page-with-images)

***Update***

Follow-up after the OP update

Using your exact post, I do not get any popups at all on the systems I tested on.

```
 $iwr=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -UseBasicParsing

 $iwr.Images

outerHTML   : <img id="id_p" class="id_avatar sw_spd" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" 
              src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7" aria-label="Profile Picture" 
              onError="FallBackToDefaultProfilePic(this)"/>
tagName     : IMG
id          : id_p
class       : id_avatar sw_spd
style       : display:none
aria-hidden : true
src         : data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7
aria-label  : Profile Picture
onError     : FallBackToDefaultProfilePic(this)
...

 $iwr.Images.src
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7
/sa/simg/sw_mg_l_4d_cct.png
http://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.fIx_Z6ywbsKCvY-PQkH8NAHaGN&amp;w=230&amp;h=170&amp;rs=1&amp;pcl=dddddd&amp;o=5&amp;pid=1.1
....
```

So, this sounds like something environmental on your host(s). So, give the below approach a shot and see if you get hit with any popups. It's more code, but may be an option, if it works for your use case.

```
Clear-Host
# Regular expression Urls terminating with '.jpg' or '.png' for domain name space
$regexDomainAddress = "[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)((.jpg(\/)?)|(.png(\/)?)){1}(?!([\w\/]+))"
((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links `
| Select-String -pattern $regexDomainAddress -Allmatches `
| ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} `
| Select-Object $_.Value -Unique).Value -replace 'href=','' `
| Select-Object -Unique

Clear-Host
# Regular expression Urls terminating with '.jpg' or '.png' for relative url
$regexRelativeUrl = "[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)((.jpg(\/)?)|(.png(\/)?)){1}(?!([\w\/]+))"
((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links `
| Select-String -pattern $regexRelativeUrl -Allmatches `
| ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} `
| Select-Object $_.Value -Unique).Value -replace 'href=','' `
| Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: I didn't receive any notification for your updates. Let me give it a try. Be back in a while.

Comment: With a minor change, yours has solved my problem. Although here, I use -UseBasicParsing, this returns all the urls to images. My previous script seemed to have been unable to scrap the somehow "masked" image urls. But, yours was capable, even with -UseBasicParsing switch. However, without -UseBasicParsing, the pop-up is still active.
  The final code is posted above.

Comment: Coolness, glad it worked out. Be sure to mar this as the answer for your use case and of course if anyone else hits up against this. Take care.